# Microsoft Enterprise Library - Filename with Servername

Tags: web-config, enterprise-library

Good Morning,

I'm trying to unify the server logs on a common network unit like

```
fileName="\\NETWORK\App\log{ServerName}.log"
```

But I don't find a parameter that allows log files with the server name

```
<add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"  type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0 listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, 
        fileName="\\NETWORK\App\Log\log{ServerName}.log" formatter="Text Formatter"  rollInterval="Day" timeStampPattern="_yyyy-MM-dd" maxArchivedFiles="30" />
```

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use environment variables in the file name.  In this case %COMPUTERNAME%:

```
<add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener"  type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0 listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, 
        fileName="\\NETWORK\App\Log\log%COMPUTERNAME%.log" formatter="Text Formatter"  rollInterval="Day" timeStampPattern="_yyyy-MM-dd" maxArchivedFiles="30" />
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the application Name? An Environment Variable for the app name? I tried %SessionName% but it didn't work.

Comment: @ptn77, you should be able to use any environment variable.  If you set a variable at application startup using [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx) you should be able to use it in the configuration and have it translated at runtime.